# mvvm cross Partial Declarations must not specify different base classes

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mvvmcross

I have some trouble with the MVVM cross declarations. Everytime i change the view from **ContentPage** to **MvxContentPage** it shows this declaration error.

```
public partial class TestView: ContentPage
{
     public TestView()
     {
        InitializeComponent();
        
        BindingContext = new TestViewModel();
     }
}
```

to this;

```
 public partial class TestView: MvxContentPage<TestViewModel>
 {
      public TestView()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }
 }
```

XAML;

```
<views:MvxContentPage xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
```

it shows me "Partial Declarations of TestView must not specify different base classes". I already tried all solutions from preview post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have specified the correct type argument and that you don't have any other class with the same name:

```
<views:MvxContentPage x:TypeArguments="viewModels:TestViewModel"
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:YourProject.ViewModels;assembly=YourProject"
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MvvmCross.Forms.Views;assembly=MvvmCross.Forms"
         x:Class="YourProject.Forms.UI.Pages.TestView">
...
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have another file somewhere in your project that has the line

```
public partial class TestView : ContentPage
```

It could be in some other folder, but still have the same namespace (particularly if you've been doing cuts-and-pastes of files).